# How to have a specific value from status command in linux programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux

I am trying to use the following command  `'/proc/' + process.pid + '/status'` programmatically. so I wrote the following

```
const ls2 = spawn('cat', ['/proc/' + process.pid + '/status'])
```

but what I am getting is along list of values as shown below.

how to have access to specific value from the the below posted list programmatically? for example, **VmSize:      813500 kB**

I wrote the the following code, but it does not work

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
var process = require('process');

const ls2 = spawn('cat', ['/proc/' + process.pid + '/status']);

ls2.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
console.log('ls2:stdout: ' + 'processId: ' + process.pid + '-->' + data.toString().split(' '));
});
```

please let me know how to modify the code I provided so I can have access to a specific value from the posted list

**results**

```
ls2:stdout: processId: 11723-->Name:    node
Umask:  0002
State:  R (running)
Tgid:   11723
Ngid:   0
Pid:    11723
PPid:   2263
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
Gid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
FDSize: 512
Groups: 4 24 27 30 46 113 128 1000 
NStgid: 11723
NSpid:  11723
NSpgid: 1885
NSsid:  1885
VmPeak:   814012 kB
VmSize:   813500 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:     29504 kB
VmRSS:     29504 kB
RssAnon:        7804 kB
RssFile:       21700 kB
RssShmem:          0 kB
VmData:    41524 kB
```

Comment: You should just open /proc/whatever/status as a file. Try to spawn a cat process to read a file and get results from console is a complicated workaround, and will get you into much more trouble than needed.

Comment: @Pac0 would you please provide an example

Comment: You want an example of reading from a file? See [here](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-read-files-in-nodejs/)

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command to do text processing and read values from file in bash / terminal. This command using these programs [`cat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut), [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep), [`cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut).

```
cat /proc/[process id]/status | grep [field_nanme] | cut -f2-
```

Example:

```
cat /proc/[process id]/status | grep Uid | cut -f2-
```

You can run this command in Node.js:

```
var process = require('process');
if (process.pid) {
    var output = system('cat /proc/' + process.pid + '/status | grep Uid | cut -f2-');
}
```